# Laravel ---- ERROR Undefined variable: decoded ---- En JWT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, jwt

En la creación del  un método **upload** de **PostController**.  Se produce un error el el **JWT**.
No solo en este método, sino en otros  como **getPostBySubCategory** de **SubCategoryController**.

Por que  a veces ignora el **try** y pasa directamente al

```
if($getIdentity){

            return $decoded;

}
```

y otras no ?

Creo que no depende del controlador, sino mas específicamente del método o alguna configuración JWT, ya que en la gran mayoría no he tenido problemas.

**JWT**

```
public function checkToken($jwt, $getIdentity=false){
    $auth = false;

    try{
        $jwt = str_replace('"','',$jwt);
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->key, ['HS256']);               
    } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        $auth = false;
    }
      catch (\DomainException $e) {
        $auth = false;
    }

    if(!empty($decoded) && is_object($decoded) && isset ($decoded->sub)){
        $auth = true;
    }
    else{
        $auth = false;
    }

    if($getIdentity){
        return $decoded;
    }
    return $auth;
}
```

**Método 1**

```
    public function upload(Request $request) {       
    // Recoger la imagen de la petición
    $image = $request->file('file0');
    // Validar imagen
    $validate = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'file0' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif'
    ]);

    // Guardar imagen
    if (!$image || $validate->fails()) {
        $data = [
            'code' => 400,
            'status' => 'erroe',
            'message' => 'Error al subir la imagen'
        ];
    } else {
        $image_name = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();

        \Storage::disc('image')->put($image_name, \File::get($image));

        $data = [
            'code' => 200,
            'status' => 'success',
            'image' => $image_name
        ];
    }
    // Devolver imagen
    return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
}
```

**Método 2**

```
    public function getSubCategoryByCategory($id) {
    $sub_category = Sub_Category::where('category_id', $id)->get();

    return response() -> json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'sub_category' => $sub_category
                    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Enric, no es una buena practica colocar el código en una imagen por favor si puedes editar tu pregunta y colocar el código en la pregunta como tienes el resto. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. Antes del **try**, basta con poner

```
$decoded = false;
```